# Azure Speaker Recognition - How to add a new key/value to a users profile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the [python sdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Python) for speaker recognition using Microsoft cognitive service [*I'm working in the Identification Folder*]; When I run the CreateProfile.py file I'm trying give a profile a user-name. So for example, I would run my main.py file and then I would try to pass the locale and **name**.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./Identification')
from CreateProfile import create_profile

name="Jane Doe"
subscriptionKey = "<my subscription key>"
locale = "en-us"

create_profile(name, subscriptionKey, locale)
```

Once I run the get profile GetProfile.py I want it to output all the user's info including their user-name. But I get this returned in the terminal.

```
Profile Name = None
Profile ID = 93affed1-ceb2-4538-9e6b-f0bd22d123b0
Locale = en-us
Enrollments Speech Time = 0.0
Remaining Enrollment Time = 30.0
Created = 2017-10-07T02:03:51.956Z
Last Action = 2017-10-07T02:03:51.956Z
Enrollment Status = Enrolling
```

I've tried editing the IdentificationProfile.py by adding things like `_PROFILE_NAME = 'identificationProfileName'` in the class, I've added a change related to this in a lot of places but I still don't see the name returning when I run GetProfile.py

This is my IdentificationProfile.py

```
import IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper
import sys

def get_profile(subscription_key, profile_id):
    """Get a speaker's profile with given profile ID

    Arguments:
    subscription_key -- the subscription key string
    profile_id -- the profile ID of the profile to resets
    """
    helper = IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper.IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper(
        subscription_key)

    profile = helper.get_profile(profile_id)

    print('Profile Name = {0}\n Profile ID = {1}\nLocale = {2}\nEnrollments Speech Time = {3}\nRemaining Enrollment Time = {4}\nCreated = {5}\nLast Action = {6}\nEnrollment Status = {7}\nName\n'.format(
        profile._profile_name,
        profile._profile_id,
        profile._locale,
        profile._name,
        profile._enrollment_speech_time,
        profile._remaining_enrollment_time,
        profile._created_date_time,
        profile._last_action_date_time,
        profile._enrollment_status))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print('Usage: python DeleteProfile.py <subscription_key> <profile_id> ')
        print('\t<subscription_key> is the subscription key for the service')
        print('\t<profile_id> the ID for a profile to delete from the sevice')
        sys.exit('Error: Incorrect usage.')
    get_profile(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot give a name to a identification profile. The [HTTP endpoint](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c068e597ed22ec38f42e) that the python SDK uses does not accept any parameters other than the locale for the voice.

You would have to map user names to identification profile IDs yourself. You can use a database for that, maybe an [Azure MySQL db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-python). Or if you're just testing things out, use an in-memory map (aka dictionary).